# CSS-only, Zoom image but not the rest

Tags: html, css, image

Using just CSS, I want to zoom in/out (ctrl+mouse wheel) on an image but keep the rest of the elements the same size.

I have the following elements:

- A container with width=80vw and height=80vh
- An image that at default zoom (100%) should be the same size as the container.

I'm using the mouse wheel because I want multiple zoom levels.

This is a representation of what I'm looking for:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsIAv.gif)

I'm missing that with the default zoom (100%) the image must have the same size as the container.

Sample code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

#container {
  border: 0.8vh solid #39d662;
  background-color: #39d662;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#container>img {
  /* zoom works without this, but at default zoom (100%) the image doesn't fit the container */
  /* height: 100%; */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <!--  image could be any size -->
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080">
</div>
```

Comment: CSS can"t get keyboard or mouse event. You need JS code.

Answer (score 0):

Style the image with `width: 100%`, `height: 100%` and `object-fit: contain` and it will size itself to fit your container without cropping. If you want the image to be cropped so that it fills/covers your container, `use object-fit: cover` instead.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

#container {
  border: 0.8vh solid #39d662;
  background-color: #39d662;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <!--  image could be any size -->
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080">
</div>
```